# Tags for hosts in SSH config file

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to group hosts by tags in `~/.ssh/config` file and use it in autocompletion?

For example lets have 2 hosts in `master` group (`host-1` and `host-2`) and 3 hosts in `slave` group (`host-3`, `host-4` and `host-5`).

What I want to achieve is whenever I type `ssh sl` and press tab it will autoexpand to `ssh slave` and 3 hosts (3,4 and 5) will be available for autocompletion that I can select from.

The only option I see right now is to hardcode tag value into `Host`, which is ugly, like:

```
Host host-1_master
   Hostname host1
Host host-2_master
   Hostname host-2
Host host-3_slave
   Hostname host-3
Host host-4_slave
   Hostname host-4
Host host-5_slave
   Hostname host-5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define more than one "alias" for a hostname. The following config should work for you:

```
Host host-1_master master1
   Hostname host1
Host host-2_master master2
   Hostname host-2
Host host-3_slave slave1
   Hostname host-3
Host host-4_slave slave2
   Hostname host-4
Host host-5_slave slave3
   Hostname host-5
```

If you want a fancy drop-down inside your terminal, you should have a look at `fzf` which supports [ssh hostname completion](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#host-names).